# Was there a real Ocean Liner called the RMS Heroic?

Tags: 20th-century, transportation

From what I've been able to find, it looks like the "RMS Heroic" is a sister-ship to the fictional "RMS Tyranic" — a ship the size of a mountain illustrated by Bruce McCall — but even that connection only comes from a Minecraft project to render the ships.

The name RMS Heroic doesn't seem to appear anywhere else except in a book of short stories about Moriarty, and neither name appears in any lists of real ships I've been able to find.

Was the RMS Heroic ever a real (perhaps renamed) ocean liner?

Answer (score 4):

The "RMS" designation stood for "Royal Mail Ship" (or Steamer) and was applied to vessels that carried mail for the British Royal Mail postal service. The first designations were assigned in the 1840's and it was not used exclusively for transatlantic liner services.

Wikipedia has a full list of [ships](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_Mail_Ship#List_of_Royal_Mail_Ships) that carried this prefix and it appears from their list that there was never a RMS Heroic (although RMS Homeric comes close).